# Pfsense : using the server to resolve hostnames as ip in local vlans

Tags: domain-name-system, vlan, local-area-network, pfsense, hostname

I made a network with 3 machines, one is a pfsense server that manage a captive portal, a dns, dhcp server and firewall rules, it is in a trunk network. The second pc is a server hosting some services and a virtual machine hosting a website it is in a vlan2. the last one is a client computer that want to access internet, the service server and the website server it is located in vlan1.
all is done on a network switch that provides vlans to seperate the client from the rest of the network.
both the client and servers are running the latest version xubunu.   except for the pfsense server  this one is running pfsense obviously. the pfsense server is the only machine allowed to have a static ip,  the others need to be using dhcp.

I want to be able to assign a domain name to the network and be able to type the hostname.domaine_name to access the website from the client pc.  but I might be missing something because I cannot recall how to accomplish the hostname resolution (there are so many hints pointing at different solution i'm lost now)

as of right now the domain name is not set because I am confused as to how to do that. I need hints as to how I can do the resolution  of hostname  in the "local network".

Comment: You'll need a DNS server and either DHCP address reservations or some kind of dynamic DNS updating by either the DHCP server or each host.